# What is the benefit of using xslt with xml if the same thing can be achieved by code behind

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

HI I RECENTLY STARTED USING XML FOR ASP.NET (VB).
My query is as follows.

1) Why should I use xslt if the same thing can be achieved by code behind?
2) Can you suggest a simple tutorial link in xslt that is understandable to newbie like me.
3) I have a xml file that looks like this

```
 <video>
      <name>name</name>
      <source>source</source>
      <category>category</category>
      <date>date</date>
      <description>description</description>
      <image>image</image>
      <tags>tags</tags>   
 </video>
```

I want to display this file in the following format

```
<ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="ImgsLabel" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' />
                <br />
                Length:
                <asp:Label ID="lengthLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("length") %>' />
                <br />
                Dateloaded:
                <asp:Label ID="DateloadedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description") %>' Visible="False" />
                <asp:Label ID="sourceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("source") %>' Visible="False" />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton id="SelectButton" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" runat="server" 
            />                   
            </ItemTemplate>
```

As you can understand that this can be easily achieved using code behind but for the sake of learning someone guide me step by step how this can be achieved using xslt in a asp.net page?

Comment: you might just want to stick with code behind...

Comment: Why use xslt when you can do the same thing in other ways?  It's just as easy to ask, Why use other ways when you can do the same thing in xslt?  Check your assumptions.

Comment: I got it thanks for all of your help. Check my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started googleing xslt examples and landed on this **[page.](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/12/22/aspnet-how-to-use-an-xmldatasource-with-a-gridview/)**
Please bear in mind that this is my first day experimenting with xml and xslt. I normally use sql datasource in my applications.

So I have a xml file which basically looks like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE video [
   <!ELEMENT video (name,embedsource,category,date,description,image,tags)>
   <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT embedsource (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT category (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT tags (#PCDATA)>
  ]> <!-- This part is the Document Type Definition -->
  <video>
  <name>somename</name>
  <embedsource>some source</embedsource>
  <category>some category</category>
  <date>16/03/2013</date>
  <description>some description</description>
  <image>some image link</image>
  <tags>sometag1,,sometag2,,sometag3,,sometag4</tags>   
  </video> <!-- This part contains the actual data -->
```

Now we have our data but we need some way of displaying/feeding this data to a control *(this can be gridview or datalist or anything that you are comfortable with)* application. I can ofcourse use string functions or some other code to achieve this but we are going to use a **transform(*You can get more information about a transform at [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/xsl_intro.asp) link.*)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
     >
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
       <video>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//video"/>
       </video>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match ="//video">
       <video>
       <xsl:attribute name="name">
       <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="description">
       <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="category">
       <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="date">
       <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="embedsource">
       <xsl:value-of select="embedsource"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:attribute name="tags">
       <xsl:value-of select="tags"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       </video>
       </xsl:template>
       </xsl:stylesheet> <!-- Notice that I am using Attribute in my xslt but in my xml
       file data is in Element form that is because DATASETS can only recognise 
       Attributes. Attributes and Elements are interchangeable in an xml file
       and it is entirely upto you. I can be wrong here please correct me if it is the
       case.  -->
```

And the final step is to configure the xml datasource. The file path would be the path to the xml file and the transform path would be the path to the xslt file. Add a data list to your application and the mad scientist within you goes muhahahahahhahaaaa.

The pro and cons of using xslt are still open and I will conclude this part soon.